# Log analysis with Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, log-analysis

I have logs with this rows:

```
in24.inetnebr.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 1839
```

where the first column (`in24.inetnebr.com`) is the host, the second (`01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400`) is the timestamp, the 3rd (`GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt HTTP/1.0`) is the downloaded page.

How can I find the last two downloaded page for every hosts with Pig?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I got a small progress, now I have rows with (casted, the date is date):
(host, date, address)
From this, how can I choose the last two address for every hosts?
Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, FYI:

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar
DEFINE SUBSTRING org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.SUBSTRING();

raw = LOAD 'nasa' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); --cast the data, to make possible the usage of string functions

rawCasted = FOREACH raw GENERATE (chararray)host as host, (chararray)xdate as xdate,(chararray)address as address; --cut out the date, and put together the used columns

rawParsed = FOREACH rawCasted GENERATE host, SUBSTRING(xdate,1,20) as xdate, address; --make sure that the not full columns are omitted

rawFiltered = FILTER rawParsed BY xdate IS NOT NULL; --cast the timestamp to timestamp format

analysisTable = FOREACH rawFiltered GENERATE host, ToDate(xdate, 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss') as xdate, address;

aTgrouped = GROUP analysisTable BY host;

resultsB = FOREACH aTgrouped {
elems=ORDER analysisTable BY xdate DESC;
two=LIMIT elems 2; --Choose the last two page

fstB=ORDER two BY xdate DESC;
fst=LIMIT fstB 1; --Choose the last page

sndB=ORDER two BY xdate ASC;
snd=LIMIT sndB 1; --Choose the previous page

GENERATE FLATTEN(group), fst.address, snd.address; --Put together the pages
};
DUMP resultsB;
```

Comment: I've made 4 analysis (two with Pig and two with Hive) on this NASA data-set, I can provide the link to the data-set and the code for the other 3 analysis, if somebody is interested.

Comment: Could you please provide me the link for analysis?